# How to get old Twitter API method working on ASP.Net site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I used to use this method for pulling tweets from my twitter to a customer feed on my site:

```
<ul id="twitter_update_list"><li>Twitter feed loading</li></ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=4">
```

However since the change to API1.1 this will not work due to the new Auth restrictions. I have seen some tutorials out there that use a PHP script to get this sort of thing working again, however because I'm running an ASP.NET application I can't just throw in a random PHP file.

Is there anyway to get this working again without PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install PHP on IIS 7 and later. Read [Setting Up PHP On IIS 7 or later](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Can I run a PHP page inside an ASP.NET application though? I already have PHP installed - but it's running the two side by side that might be a problem.

Comment: No, but you could have an ASP.NET page that used jQuery's `.ajax()` method to call a PHP script and return the data to your ASP.NET page, which I believe is what you wanted for your Twitter functionality, right?

Comment: Yeah that is what I wanted - right looks like I have research to do :) - thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)